# What different parts make up pg_database_size. And can I access them individually for graphing?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to understand the value of the different [object size functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE). I realised, that `pg_database_size` is larger than `pg_total_relation_size`, even if the DB contains only one table.

Here is a little script demonstrating this:

```
CREATE TABLE hello(id serial NOT NULL primary key, comment text UNIQUE);
INSERT INTO hello (comment) VALUES ('hello'), ('world');

SELECT
    pg_database_size('sizetest'),
    pg_indexes_size('hello'),
    pg_table_size('hello'),
    pg_total_relation_size('hello'),
    (pg_indexes_size('hello') + pg_table_size('hello')) = pg_total_relation_size('hello') AS test1
;
```

In the end I'd like to pull out as much detail as possible to create a munin graph and plot those values over time. It would be nice to be able to break down `pg_database_size` into it's components and draw them as stacked areas. Having the size of TOAST would be nice too, but I can't quite figure out how to get at those.

Comment: A database contains more than just _your_ table. It contains a lot of internal tables: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html

Comment: As I understand it, those catalogs you link are global to the cluster. Not the database. I don't want to track the size of the cluster as a whole, just the individual databases.

Comment: Not exactly. There are 8 cluster-wide tables, but others belong to each database.